# Code development (specifically text editor) while using a netbook

Tags: text-editor, google-chrome-os

I have been using a chrome book for a few months now. I also have been designing a web page. A lot of the work can be done via word press's lame gui, but like any coder, I want to use a real text editor, specifically vi/vim.

I have done some searching around. I found one java script implementation of vi, but it's not good enough IMO to use. Conversely, I'd like to ssh into one of my *nix boxes and use vi that way, although you cannot do that from web pages it seems. HTTP vs TCP issues. Not sure if WebSockets will be able to get around this.

Lastly, I've been looking at plugins. While some decent ones seem to be available for Firefox, the Chrome division is lacking severely.

One desparate try is vnc, but this chromebook has no javascrip support, not can I get the HTML5 vnc running quite right.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit/Update:
Thanks for everyone's effort in answering. I quickly abandoned coding on the netbook, but it looks like some great answers were provided.

Comment: chromebooks can ssh (hit ctrl-alt-t to get to crosh prompt), although admittedly at least on the CR-48 the tiny, nonadjustable font size makes coding difficult.

Answer (score 3):

I am on a Samsung ARM Chromebook and I do a lot of development work in Vim.  Here's how I prefer to do it:

Enable [Developer Mode](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/developer-mode), then download [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton).

Open a shell:

```
<ctrl><alt>t
```

...and install Ubuntu command-line environment

```
sudo sh -e crouton -t cli-extra
```

Enter the chroot using

```
sudo enter-chroot
```

From inside the chroot install vim

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

There are lots more instructions and examples on the crouton github page.
I prefer the command line only version because I can just have Ubuntu in another tab, and all the Chromebook keyboard shortcuts Just Work.

Answer (score 1):

You have few options:

- Cloud9, an IDE for JavaScript, Python, PHP, and Ruby. Cloud9 uses the HTML5 FileSystem capability and AppCache to sync files, so you can even code offline. It got some really nice features that I find myself using a lot: github integration, chat, the ability to work and do reviews on your code without any pain of ‘new/other’ tools.
- Kodingen is an Online Development Environment including Code Editor, Cloud Hosting etc'. I haven’t play with it (yet) – but I’ve heard some friends that like it.
- Codey - Easy to use code editor for HTML, PHP, CSS, JS. They are in Chrome web store.
- Akshell - Server-side JavaScript development and hosting platform. They got some git integration built in their IDE.

I hope it helps.
For more, I've posted something about this Q few months ago: http://greenido.wordpress.com/2011/07/04/web-developers-and-the-new-chromebook/

Answer (score 0):

There are web shells: [this](http://www.askapache.com/ajax/php-and-ajax-shell-console.html) is the first one that came up with a search, but there are others. Be sure to use HTTPS and place it behind a authentication gateway. I can't vouch for how well they handle vim and it's interesting screen modes, but hopefully one of them might work.

Answer (score 0):

How about [SourceKit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iieeldjdihkpoapgipfkeoddjckopgjg)? Unforunately the bindings are closer to textmate, it has great highlighting and IMHO the text will be easier on the eyes than if you were looking at tiny shell font.